# Congruence of $n^n$ modulo 5

Tags: divisibility, congruences

Given a integer $n$, determine the remainder of dividing $n^n$ for 5 in terms of an adequate congruence for n.

So I'm really stuck in this exercise.

By Euler little theorem I know $n^4 \equiv 1 \mod5$ if $(n,5)=1$

Then, I'll be inclined to use somthing like $n = 4k + r, 0 \leq r \leq 3$

the problem is how do I determine the $n$s that actually are $(n,5)=1$ and those who are not...

Comment: You know that in the base, you have a period of $5$. In the exponent, the remainder modulo $4$ is the important thing. So what about combining these two and consider $n$ modulo ...?

Comment: 20? I tried, But didn't help me to find nothing of interest

Comment: You need to check based on $n\pmod 4$ and $n\pmod 5$, which is equivalent to $n\pmod {20}$. $n\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $n\equiv 0\pmod 5$ are obvious...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews for all the possible remainders?

Comment: Some of them are more obvious than others, but yes. @FranckN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $5|n$ then the answer is $0$

If $n\equiv 1 \mod 5$ then the remainder will always be $1$

If $n\equiv -1 \mod 5$ then the remainder will be $1$ or $4$ dependent on whether $n$ is even or odd (note: $-1$ has order $2$ in the multiplicative group of non-zero residues, and the answer therefore depends on $n \mod 2$).

If $n\equiv 2,3 \mod 5$ - these being primitive roots - you have four cases for each depending on the residue class of $n \mod 4$.